# openiddict, angular, which flow type to use (without auth server redirect page)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, openiddict

I'm new to **oauth2** and **openid connect**, so, many concepts are still obscure for me - and I'm here for advice

I'm planning to build a **web app** with the following components:

1. SPA with **angular**
2. **web API** with asp.net core 2.x
3. auth server (separate - not in the same project of web API) with
   **openiddict** 2.x

I own the three components = there is a complete **trust** between auth server and SPA client app.

I need the user to login (enter username and password) and register directly in the Angular client (**without redirect** to auth server register or log in or permission page)

*my questions are:*

1. what is the appropriate **flow** to use in this situation?
2. regarding the angular client: what is the best auth package or library to
   use with the angular client that is best **compatible** and easy to
   use with openiddict in the auth server
3. I need advice about the **workflow** of the app (between the 3
   components)
4. is there a tutorial (better than the example) for this stack?

any answer to **any** of these questions is well appreciated, thanks in advance